# Adding a grouped product to cart via the rest api

Tags: magento2, rest-api, grouped-products

I'm trying to POST a grouped product to my magento 2 site. Doing this for a simple product is easy enough. How to do it can be found [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-add-items.html).

But what is doesn't specify is how to add a **grouped product**. 
I have tried something like this:

```
POST rest/V1/carts/mine/items


{
"cartItem": {
    "sku": "arduino-kit-10000",
    "qty": "1",
    "quote_id": "5",
    "product_links": [
        {
            "sku": "arduino-kit-10000",
            "linked_product_sku": "13620748",
            "extension_attributes": [
                {
                    "qty": "5"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "sku": "arduino-kit-10000",
            "linked_product_sku": "1111111130",
            "extension_attributes": [
                {
                    "qty": "5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
   "message": "Property \"ProductLinks\" does not have accessor method \"getProductLinks\" in class \"Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\CartItemInterface\".",
```

Does anyone know how this can be done? 
Or if I can just add the simple products by themselves and let Magento know they belong to a grouped product?

Answer (score 0):

use POST rest/V1/products

```
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "Luma-Group",
    "name": "Luma Group Of Bags",
    "attribute_set_id": 15,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "grouped",
    "extension_attributes": {
        "category_links": [
            {
                "position": 0,
                "category_id": "4"
            }
        ],
        "stock_item": {
            "is_in_stock": true
        }
    },
    "product_links": [
        {
            "sku": "Luma-Group",
            "link_type": "associated",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB04",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 0,
            "extension_attributes": {
                "qty": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "sku": "Luma-Group",
            "link_type": "associated",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB03",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 1,
            "extension_attributes": {
                "qty": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "sku": "Luma-Group",
            "link_type": "associated",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB05",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 2,
            "extension_attributes": {
                "qty": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "description",
            "value": "This is Group description for product."
        }
    ]
  }
}
```